# Monodevelop Unity - Breakpoints not being hit on iOS device

Tags: ios, macos, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I'm running MonoDevelop on OSX with Unity and an iPad. My debugger attaches to the iPad correctly but all of the breakpoints aren't viable, like the .mdb files are out of sync.

I've tried copying them all to the /Assets/Plugins folder but still no joy, any ideas on why the breakpoints don't resolve properly?

Comment: Are you using unity remote?

Comment: No, just MonoDevelop. Do I need to use Unity Remote?

Comment: For android, it is the only way I know. Here some links that may help you. (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ios-remote-debugging.163281/) (http://docs.unity3d.com/432/Documentation/Manual/Debugger.html)

Comment: Thanks Ronaldo, I have looked through the debugger manual already. That got me to the point where I could attach the debugger but for some reason the breakpoints wont match up.